# Java Web App over App Engine error access

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, objectify

I am developing a Java Web App using Google App Engine, the app use Maven, JSF and Objectify and works fine in devserver but in production give the following error:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized: Critical error during deployment: 
  java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:375)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:565)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:56)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:131)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:378)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:575)
    at com.sun.faces.util.MojarraThreadFactory.newThread(MojarraThreadFactory.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:599)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:931)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1611)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:542)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.initConfigMonitoring(ConfigureListener.java:480)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:199)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:174)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:484)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Someone have faced a similar problem and can help me with a hint or maybe know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Adam points Google App Engine has some restrictions especially with native threads as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#threads

In JSF a solution  for the single threaded enviroment used by Google App Engine is described here:

http://java.wildstartech.com/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/javaserver-faces-20/configuring-javaserver-faces-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine/javaserverfaces-20-and-google-app-engine-compatibility-issues

Additionally there could be another problem handling the JSF sessions, a possible solution is described here:
[Session lost in Google App Engine using JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259457/session-lost-in-google-app-engine-using-jsf)

And finally a good detailed example of JSF in App Engine is described here:
http://java.wildstartech.com/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/javaserver-faces-22/configuring-jsf-22-to-run-on-the-google-app-engine-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times, see the following questions for examples:

- [java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
  (java.lang.RuntimePermission
  modifyThreadGroup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229323/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission)
- [Google App Engine modifyThreadGroup
  problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708817/google-app-engine-modifythreadgroup-problem)

Certain operations with threads [are disallowed in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#threads), and some part of your code is breaking the rules.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer, is true app engine doesn't allow certain operations with threads that are part of jsf and I found a specific solution to this problem, soon I'll post this.